# Share score on Twitter of your Unity game

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, share, facebook-unity-sdk

**How to share the score on twitter for your Unity game?** I need to ensure that **the user can't edit the score** while tweeting about it. Also want to share a screenshot of the score.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using the [WWW Class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) and the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public).